# application level error after symfony update to 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

today i upgraded from sf2.8 to sf3.4... first i faced some errors because i did not reworked the sf standard files, now these errors are gone and i'm stuck with an error on application level. under sf2.8 it was not an issue and tbh i dont understand why its now.

error triggered hitting "/":

`[Tue Oct 02 11:37:31.885382 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 24:tid 140202295097088] [client 172.29.0.1:37964] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 2 passed to TheApp\\FrontendBundle\\Services\\UrlAliasService::__construct() must be an instance of TheApp\\FrontendBundle\\Routing\\Router, instance of Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Routing\\Router given, called in /var/www/var/cache/dev/ContainerV5bxhc0/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 3678 in /var/www/src/TheApp/FrontendBundle/Services/UrlAliasService.php:25\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/var/cache/dev/ContainerV5bxhc0/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(3678): TheApp\\FrontendBundle\\Services\\UrlAliasService->__construct(Object(Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityManager), Object(Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Routing\\Router), Object(Cocur\\Slugify\\Slugify))\n#1 /var/www/var/cache/dev/ContainerV5bxhc0/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(3698): ContainerV5bxhc0\\appDevDebugProjectContainer->getTheApp_UrlaliasserviceService()\n#2 /var/www/var/cache/dev/ContainerV5bxhc0/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(3872): Contain...\n'`

so the service "UrlAliasService" takes 3 parameters:

```
...
use TheApp\FrontendBundle\Routing\Router;
...
public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, Router $router, Slugify $slugify)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->urlRepository = $this->em->getRepository('TheAppFrontendBundle:UrlAlias');
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->slugify = $slugify;
        $this->urlAliasInProcess = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

these 3 parameters get wired in services.yml:

```
theapp.urlaliasservice:
        class: TheApp\FrontendBundle\Services\UrlAliasService
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@router", "@cocur_slugify"]
```

here is the router class, extending BaseRouter:

```
namespace TheApp\FrontendBundle\Routing;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router as BaseRouter;
...
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;

class Router extends BaseRouter implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, $resource, array $options = array(), RequestContext $context = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($container, $resource, $options, $context);
        $this->setContainer($container);
    }

    public function getGenerator()
    {
        $generator = parent::getGenerator();
        $generator->setContainer($this->container);
        return $generator;
    }

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

so the error tells me that the argument passed in is from type TheApp\FrontendBundle\Routing\Router .... but it actually is from type Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router .... reading the code this error makes no sense right? the class TheApp\FrontendBundle\Routing\Router extends Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router so how can it be not an instance from it? help and explanation is very very much appreciated.

Comment: Is autowire/autoconfig enabled by any chance?  You would have had to add a _defaults section to your services file so probably not.  And just for grins you could typehint against RouterInterface instead of Router.  Though like you I don't think is the problem.

Comment: i tried adding the _defaults to services.yml with "autowire: true/false, autoconfigure: true/false, public: false"

Comment: public need to be true for sure.  autowire and autoconfigure should be false.  Best to just not have a defaults section at all at least until you get things working.

Comment: oh sorry, i mistyped... actually using: "autowire: false, autoconfigure: false, public: true" -  and i was not using the _defaults section at all in the first place

Comment: @Cerad do you know what "@router" stand for in sf3.4? any different to sf2.8?

Comment: Okay.  So that rules that out.  I assume you overrode the ATrouter service definition?  There have been changes to the framework's router.  It now implements what is known as a ServiceSubscriperInterface.  Don't know for sure but I'm guessing it is hardcoded somehow.  You might need to look at the framework bundle extension to see what it going on.  Out of the box, "bin/console debug:container router" shows it is mapped to the framework's router.

Comment: This may or may not help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021326/symfony-3-3-custom-router

Comment: well there is this Router.php in src/TheApp/FrontendBundle/Routing/Router.php but i have not overridden the ATrouter in services.yml with "router: class: ... arguments: ..."

Comment: @Cerad i was able to get rid of the error with this configuration, but it seems... wierd?
router:
        class: TheApp\FrontendBundle\Routing\Router
        arguments: ["@service_container", "", [], null]

also the next error followed... could this be a sideeffect from this maybe not valid configuration? im pretty new to sf and not able to get this wired in by brain.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52622002/sonata-twig-error-after-symfony-update-2-6-to-3-4

Comment: Consider updating your question with the new config.  There is an edit link under it.  Comments don't format well.  And post what class you get with "bin/console debug:container router".  What I am not seeing at this point is how your customized router is becoming the default router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's obvious that `@router` is a Router service defined by `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router`. Instead of it in `arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@router", "@cocur_slugify"]` you should inject your service, for example `theapp.router`. You have a few choices here:

1. declare your service as `theapp.route`
2. [override](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/bundles/override.html#services-configuration) `router` with your service , but I would not do it.

Comment: It is not so much a question of injecting a custom router into a specific class but in coaxing the framework to use the custom router in the first place.  If you just inject the custom one then you will end up with two routers floating around causing all sorts of amusing side effects.

Comment: i configured router.default to only use our own custom class (services.yml), this answer was leading the right direction, thanks to all of you guys