# sonata/twig error after symfony update 2.6 to 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, interface, twig, sonata

im updating a project from sf2.6(php5.6) to sf3.4(php7.1)... its going well but now im stuck with an error i cant figure out how to fix it

error output:
`PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 2 passed to Sonata\\FormatterBundle\\Formatter\\Pool::add() must implement interface Sonata\\FormatterBundle\\Formatter\\FormatterInterface, boolean given, called in /var/www/var/cache/dev/ContainerMklcxqq/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 4924 in /var/www/vendor/sonata-project/formatter-bundle/src/Formatter/Pool.php:43\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/var/cache/dev/ContainerMklcxqq/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(4924): Sonata\\FormatterBundle\\Formatter\\Pool->add('twig', true, NULL)\n#1 /var/www/var/cache/dev/ContainerMklcxqq/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(3475): ContainerMklcxqq\\appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSonata_Formatter_PoolService()\n#2 /var/www/var/cache/dev/ContainerMklcxqq/getAssetic_AssetManagerService.php(8): ContainerMklcxqq\\appDevDebugProjectContainer->getTwigService()\n#3 /var/www/var/cache/dev/ContainerMklcxqq/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(1349): require('/var/www/var/ca...')\n#4 /v...\n'`

if i check the mentioned line (4924) in the container i find:

```
$instance->add('twig', ${($_ = isset($this- >services['sonata.formatter.text.twigengine']) ? $this- 
>services['sonata.formatter.text.twigengine'] : $this- 
>getSonata_Formatter_Text_TwigengineService()) && false ?: '_'}, NULL);
```

when i check the actual service with "bin/console debug:container sonata.formatter.text.twigengine" i get the following, which is good, i guess:

```
Information for Service "sonata.formatter.text.twigengine"
==========================================================

 ---------------- ------------------------------------------------
  Option           Value
 ---------------- ------------------------------------------------
  Service ID       sonata.formatter.text.twigengine
  Class            Sonata\FormatterBundle\Formatter\TwigFormatter
  Tags             sonata.text.formatter
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        no
  Autoconfigured   no
 ---------------- ------------------------------------------------
```

and finally i checked the actual TwigFormatter class, which leads to this post:

```
final class TwigFormatter implements FormatterInterface
```

how is this error possible and am i supposed to fix this or is any package update needed? im using the newest version of the sonata-project/formatter-bundle and also the newest version of twig/twig.

help and explanation is much appreciated. thanks guys.

Comment: You'll have to check all changelogs and upgrade notices of Symfony, and also of sonata and twig.

Comment: i fixed all codebase related deprecations before updating - but well, i will take another look then

Comment: This bug seems to come from Sonata and Symfony themselves, see https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/5238 then https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug comes from Symfony, see [BUG: FormatterBundle\Formatter\Pool::add() must implement interface](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/5238) then [[DI] Error on dumped container for inlined services](http://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28658)

You'll have to wait for [this fix](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/22aec2490ca3e06f9307a2e47b51087c2129720d) to be merged, or if you're a player, apply it yourself.